# How to password protect ActiveAdmin? -- Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

In addition to the devise base authentication that ActiveAdmin uses, **is where a way I can use .htaccess type authentication also as a second protection layer?**

If not .htaccess, **is there's a way I can use `authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic` with ActiveAdmin?**

Answer (score 0):

In your application_controller.rb

```
http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "leonel", :password => "somethingrandom"
```

http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1

Comment: what if I want it only for the active admin routes?

Answer (score 0):

Leonel gave a good answer, it's just missing a little condition:

In your application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: 'name', password: 'password', if: :admin_controller?

  def admin_controller?
    self.class < ActiveAdmin::BaseController
  end
end
```